# AWS redirect URL with AngularJS running in Node.js server

Tags: node.js, angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

I´m trying to config a website hosted in AWS EC2 instance. But Im a bit mixed!!

I have an AngularJS application running in a Node.js server listening on port 1234. This site is deployed correctly, so when I get the url in a browser ec2-instance-public-dns:1234/app/index.html I see my site perfectly.

In the other hand, I registered a domain name in GoDaddy. I set up a Route 53 and the DNS names in GoDaddy.

I see, I also have a load balancer listening in port 80, that is redirecting to port 1234.

What I need is to link my domain with my site in the path ec2-instance-public-dns:1234/app/index.html

All this stuff is not working. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hello Rober,
Are you able to resolve the problem with ec2 instance,

I am facing the same issue with angular2.
It's working fine with "ec2-52-40-204-248.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:4000",  but when I change the host name with my IP address it's not working at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Is there is reason why you don't have Node listen to 80 or 8080 ?
- Does the DNS redirection work ? -> Can you access your site with www.yourdomainname.com:1234 ?
  -> If no, then check your dns config, you should not have to deal with port routing at that level.
- Are you using Linux as your EC2 instance ? If yes, reroute port 80 toward port 1234 as explained here (http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-port-redirection-with-iptables/).

That how I do it, hope that helps.

Comment: I really appreciate all your comments. I will check everyone of them. Once I have all this working, if I understand right if I get www.domain.com I would get ec2-instance-public-dns:1234 or ec2-instance-public-dns:80 (depending on the port configured), but my welcome page is in browser ec2-instance-public-dns:1234/app/index.html (I mean, the point is app/index.html path), I need to get this view when I request www.domain.com

Comment: You will achieve this using for example a nodejs module such as Express that allows to define routes (in your case '/' should render app/index.html)

Comment: Correct, This is what I need. Unfortunately, I have no idea about Express, I will have to have a look at it. The only problem I wouldn´t like to make my life hard with this. Do you think it worth to invest in this or should I replace this node.js with a NGINX server (in example).

Comment: This is my current node.js server script http://plnkr.co/edit/2VESE6q26I0AyF2r81y4 . Could you help me to update it for this routing?

Comment: I would not be clearer that this awesome tutorial that I recommand you http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/node-and-angular-to-do-app-application-organization-and-structure